# Checking whether a graph is bipartite using BFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, time-limit-exceeded, breadth-first-search

I am solving a simple problem that checks whether a graph is two-colourable (bipartite graph). I am using BFS for this approach using C++ STL. I've replaced `cin` and `cout` with `scanf` and `printf` as suggested by fellow programmers but still the judge reports TLE.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int flag = 1;

class Graph
{
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;

    public:
        Graph(int V);
        void addEdge(int v, int w);
        void BFS(int s);
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[1000001];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
    adj[w].push_back(v);
}

void Graph::BFS(int s)
{
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    string *color = new string[1000001];
    for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
        visited[i] = false;
    list<int> queue;
    queue.push_back(s);
    visited[s] = true;
    color[s] = "red";
    list<int>::iterator i;
    flag = 1;
    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        s = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();

        for(i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); i++)
        {
            if(!visited[*i])
            {
                visited[*i] = true;
                if(color[s] == "red")
                    color[*i] = "blue";
                if(color[s] == "blue")
                    color[*i] = "red";
                queue.push_back(*i);
            }
            else
            {
                if(color[s] == color[*i])
                    flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    int T, bugs, edges, from, to;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    int p = T;
    while(T--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d", &bugs, &edges);
        Graph g(bugs+1);
        for(int i=0; i<edges; i++)
        {
            scanf("%d%d", &from, &to);
            g.addEdge(from, to);
        }

        g.BFS(from);

        if(!flag)
            printf("Scenario #%d:\nSuspicious bugs found!\n", p-T);
        else
            printf("Scenario #%d:\nNo suspicious bugs found!\n", p-T);

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bool *visited = new bool[V];   string *color = new string[1000001];`  This is a gigantic memory leak.  `using C++ STL.`  So why didn't you use `std::vector` here?

Comment: "replaced cin and cout with scanf and printf". You shouldn't have done that. You should look into [ios_base::sync_with_stdio](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/). In general, replacing C++ with C isn't going to speed things up. For a problem such as this, the C++ solution should be as fast as the C solution. Don't get distracted by language wars when you've got important issues to consider. Now you've got a bizarre mixture of C++ and C, which is going to be difficult for anybody to work with

Comment: have you used any sort of code profiling tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.prepare) to look at where you code is spending time?

Comment: I am not too comfortable with stl vectors. Although I know how to use them as simple arrays, I will have to do some reading on how to replace all list declarations by vectors. Blindly replacing list<int> by vector<int> doesn't seem to work. I will do some googling and get back!

Answer (score 3):

Stop using `std::list`, which is a doubly linked list and does not support fast random access. You should use `std::vector` instead, supporting `O(1)` random access.

Instead of

```
list<int> *adj;
```

You can have a vector of vectors, which will be not only faster, but also memory-leak free.

Comment: Note to keep the use of `std::list` for the queue.

Comment: @andars No, he should switch to `std::queue`

Comment: Sure, just don't change it to `std::vector`.

Comment: Anally retentive nag. Doubly linked list is the the most obvious std::list implementation candidate, but, if I remember correctly, not mandated. The only relevant requirements on std::list are for constant time insert and remove, and there is no requirement in list for speedy access, so it probably doesn't exist and the point holds.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have stated, another optimization is to remove doing things like this:

```
bool *visited = new bool[V];
string *color = new string[1000001];
for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
    visited[i] = false;
```

You do this each and every time the `Graph::BFS` function is called.  Not only do you call the allocator each and every time, your function does not deallocate the memory, thus creating huge memory leaks.

Looking at your code, the better approach is to use `vector` and to move those items within your `Graph` class itself.

```
class Graph
{
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;
    std::vector<bool> visited;
    std::vector<std::string> color;

    public:
        Graph(int V);
        void addEdge(int v, int w);
        void BFS(int s);
};
```

and then:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
void Graph::BFS(int s)
{
    visited.resize(V);
    color.resize(V);
    std::fill(visited.begin(), visited.end(), false);
    //...
}
```

This is more optimal and doesn't leak memory.  Why is it more optimal?  The only price you pay from the allocator is on the first call of `BFS`.  A subsequent call will issue a `resize`, but `vector` is smart enough to not allocate any further memory, since the vector's have already been sized to `V` number of items.

Comment: Thank you for the code! Now I understand better. Will try this out and resubmit.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it will make the code fast enough to pass your test.  But I can tell you that the code will be faster.

Comment: I made changes exactly as you've suggested in the above anser. Everything working fine with the given test cases. This time its a segmentation fault but not TLE. Anything else that you can guess if the resize() thing? I am unable to understand the reason for memory issues even with the use of vectors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are 2 issues with your code where you can lessen or eliminate segmentation faults.  1) Use `std::vector<std::list<int>>` instead of `std::list<int>*`.  2) Your for loops use indices within the vector's that may not be valid.  For example, if you write a loop that goes from 0 to `someVector.size()`, then your index is safe to use only for `someVector`, not for another vector.  Your loops use an index value meant for one vector, and then blindly uses it for other vectors in the loop.

Comment: For example `if(color[s] == "red")`  How do you know that `s` is a valid index?  Maybe to ensure that you don't have an issue, that vector possibly should be a `std::map<int, string>`?  Then even if you're "out of bounds", the worse that could happen is that you create an empty value in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `std::list`, use `std::vector`, as a `std::vector` provides fast random access(`O(1)`) but a `std::list` does not. Another thing you can do, although I am not sure if that  would be completely relevant, is that instead of using `new` to allocate a bulk of memory in your constructor, re-write the functions so that you use `push_back` into your vector of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2D array (array of arrays) instead of a list as long as you know what the size will be from the beginning.